# issue in if else statement with null condition in python

Tags: python

I have below src_input data.

```
2022-09-02 12:25:28.390508,--1,    table_name column_name business_key_name select_column_names  \
0  DimCurrency   FirstName                                         

  where_condition schema_name        schema_table  
0                      testdb  testdb.DimCurrency
```

below is mycode:

```
    try:
        if src_input['column_name'] is not None and src_input['where_condition'].isnull():
            #print("test", src_input['where_condition'].isnull())
            sql = 'select ' + src_input["column_name"] + ' as src_clmn from ' + 
            src_input['schema_table']
            sql = sql[0]
            df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db_conn)
            loging(datetime.datetime.now(), 'df1', df1)
            return df1

        elif pd.notnull(src_input['column_name']) and pd.notnull(src_input['where_condition']):

            sql = 'select ' + src_input["column_name"] + ' as src_clmn from ' + 
            src_input['schema_table'] +' where ' + src_input['where_condition']
            sql = sql[0]
            print(sql)
```

my if else condition is not working. `src_input['where_condition'].isnull()` statement output is true ,so ideally if condition should run. not sure what is wrong in my code.

if i only put `src_input['column_name'] is not None` in if staement thn my if condition sql is running fine.

Have tried below thing as well but no luck.

```
pd.notnull(src_input['where_condition'])
src_input['where_condition'] is None
src_input['column_name'] is not None and not src_input['where_condition'].isnull()
```

Comment: What is the type `src_input['where_condition']`, did you try printing the type ? Which error do you catch in your except statement ? Do you print this error ?

Comment: ```print(type(src_input['where_condition']))``` is """<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>"""
exception error: 2022-09-02 12:56:55.954633,src_inp,The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are dealing with a DataFrame and you need the row of the dataframe if you want the conditions to work fine. Try to do something like that:

```
if not src_input.iloc[0]['column_name'].isna() and src_input.iloc[0]['where_condition'].isnull():
    #do something here
```

with iloc u are selecting the first row (you can iterate each individual row or make a vectorized function to iterate them)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!
i am using ```src_input['column_name'] is not None``` its working fine and as per your explanation its should not work if that is the case.the issue is when i am giving another condition after AND , and that column itself is nan/null (['where_condition']``` is not working ).